# FileLocator.toFileURL throwing NPE in IBM WebSphere bundle

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, osgi

Currently, I'm facing an issue where I'm trying to get a WSDL resource from my bundle classpath and then call FileLocator.toFileURL to convert it from a bundle resource to a file resource. At runtime, the method throws a NullPointerException while trying to get an instance of the URLConverter, and I'm pretty baffled as to why this could happen. Below is the code that I'm using.

```
URL configURL = Preference.class.getResource("/META-INF/wsdl/Preference.wsdl");

if (configURL != null && configURL.getProtocol() != "file") {
    System.out.println("URL is not a file. Trying to convert from non-standard to something reference-able.");
    URL wsdlURL = null;

    try {
        wsdlURL = FileLocator.toFileURL(configURL);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
         System.out.println("IOException caught");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e1) {
        System.out.println("NullPointerException caught");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RuntimeException e1) {
        System.out.println("RuntimeException caught");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        System.out.println("generic Exception caught");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    PREFERENCE_WSDL_LOCATION = wsdlURL;
} else {
    System.out.println("URL is a file.");
    PREFERENCE_WSDL_LOCATION = configURL;
}
```

When I run the code locally in RAD, it works fine. However, as I think almost everyone who develops OSGi code in Eclipse finds with these kinds of things, it ends up crashing when it's deployed. For me specifically, it is packed into an OSGi Composite Bundle Archive (CBA) and deployed to a WebSphere v8.5.5 app server. Below is the error that I keep running into and its stack trace.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Activator.getURLConverter(Activator.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.toFileURL(FileLocator.java:205)
    at Preference.<clinit>(Preference.java:37)
```

I did a few sanity checks to make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious. The configURL variable is returning a value (`bundleresource://2.fwk685840929/META-INF/wsdl/Preference.wsdl`), and all of the dependencies I know of that are necessary for this workflow are added in my classpath (mainly the equinox and eclipse.osgi libraries).

I've google'd all over the place, and found two main resources: the source code for [FileLocator](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.2/org.eclipse.equinox/common/3.6.100/org/eclipse/core/runtime/FileLocator.java?av=f) and [Activator](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.2/org.eclipse.equinox/common/3.6.100/org/eclipse/core/internal/runtime/Activator.java#Activator.getURLConverter%28java.net.URL%29) which are both "present at the scene of the crime", and [this Eclipse bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=219645) for the exact same line number I'm seeing in my stack trace. However, neither makes sense, because the bug report states that this error would come about from an OSGi plugin not being available - how could this be possible if I'm literally deploying an OSGi bundle to WebSphere's OSGi ecosystem? - and if the line number in grepcode is to be trusted, then the error is apparently the urlTrackers variable which seems like it would be different from a bundle issue and not really something I can control.

I need some help here because I feel like I'm overthinking this a bit. How can I get the FileConverter class to actually work at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I think the JavaDoc comment is referring to the availability of the `org.eclipse.osgi` plugin which contains the `bundleentry` URL converter needed by `FileLocator`.

I don't think `FileLocator` is really designed to work outside of the Eclipse RCP environment.

Comment: What do you mean by the availability of the `org.eclipse.osgi` plugin? It's in my classpath and even added as optional imported packages in my MANIFEST.MF. Besides, if it wasn't available, wouldn't I be getting ClassNotFound or ClassNoDef exceptions instead of NPEs?

Comment: You get NPE because the code is looking for an OSGi service and not finding it, that doesn't give class not found errors.

Comment: There are lots of different OSGi services. This code is looking for a service called `org.eclipse.osgi.service.urlconversion.URLConverter` provided by the `org.eclipse.osgi` plugin. If Websphere doesn't provide that service this won't work.